# Android ListView: How to change the content of the list?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and the idea is that when the user types than the only strings presented to
the user will begin with that the user wrote.

If every Android device would have had a physical keyboared I could of achieved this with this simple code :

```
      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

but as you probably know some devices like the Samsung galaxi S don't have a physical keyboared.

What I did is create a simple layout file with only an EditText and I used the addHeaderView method so I now have an EditText (the user can type in it) above the list.
I want to use addTextChangedListener so I can react to what the user types.

The question is how to change the display so it will only show the strings I want (I don't have a problem finding those strings, the problem is how to update the current dispay)
Or if there is another solution to overcome the fact that some devices don't have a physical keyboared it's also fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the current dispay" ?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani - to change what strings the user see.
The idea is to do what setTextFilterEnabled(true) does on a device with a physical keyboared when the user types something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you want to implement something like: ListView should be updated according to the value typed by user, if this is the case then here is an example: [Android ListView with Searchbox Sort items](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-listview-searchbox-sort-items)

Comment: I'm having a small problem with the code : 
When I type one character into the EditText it works ok, when I try to type another character say 'a' and then 'b' than I see b written down (looks like a toast) and strings that starts with "ab" are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to filter your displayed list in an AsyncTask and then update your list in your adapter. Via notifyDataSetChanged the list is then updated to show only the items you want.
This may not be an elegant solution but it worked for me.

EDIT:
This should work

```
   void setTextChangedListenerToSearchBox(EditText etFilter) {

    if (etFilter == null)
        return;

    etFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // nothing done here
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // nothing done here
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (s.toString() != null) {
                searchupdate(s.toString());
            }
        }

    });
}


void searchupdate(String s)
{
    final List<String> currentItems = new ArrayList<String>(yourCurrentlyDisplayedItems);

    (new AsyncTask<String,Void,List<String>>() {

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            List<String> listitems = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(String item : currentItems) {
                if(item.contains(params[0])) {
                    listitems.add(item);
                }
            }
            return listitems;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result)
        {
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(result);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }).execute(s);
}
```